# Which pieces were used to make the flexible mesh skin for the life size Lego Bugatti?

Tags: part-identification, technic, building, piece-usage

In the linked [video](https://youtu.be/n-RtJOfFlZU), around the 1:50 - 1:55 mark, a person can be seen picking up a flexible hexagonal mesh, and bringing it to the side of the vehicle. Also, close ups are visible around 2:03 - 2:37. Last, the are apparently two styles of mesh being used, one light colored one dark colored.

What are the Lego parts used to build these two meshes?

Comment: They appear to be Technic lift arms, beams and hinge elements. I wonder if BrickLink has this inventoried yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a difference in a shape of triangles (that's how they mention them in the video) seen in Dark Azure as well as Dark Blue colors. However there are two shapes - bigger and smaller triangles. Smaller triangle's edge is half the length of bigger one - you can attach two of these to bigger triangle.

Larger one requires parts listed below. I didn't include half bushes seen in some images (funny thing is that half of same assembly had them, while the other didn't) as they put too much stress into assembly. It is also worth mentioning LEGO used a lot of parts which cannot be found in any of sets.

[image]

Smaller one needs these:

[image]

Then they are connected together with either of two following parts (both seen in use). First one is made of rubber so it allows some twisting and stretching which is what allows the skin to take shape.

[image] [image]

**Warning.** I've built both versions and some parts here are a bit stressed (definitely illegal connections involved) which means they could deform over time.

[image]

[image]

**Note**. I've missed 3 pieces of 3L half thickness Technic beams in smaller triangle in my assembly to cover some axles, however part list has correct amount.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you meant about the comment, "used a lot of parts which cannot be found in any of sets"? Impressive answer, and the sample models you built are very appreciated!

Comment: @nijineko LEGO produce, from time to time, parts for various projects in colors not available in any of retail sets. Bugatti in the video is not an exception. If you look closer in the video, you'll notice half width 3L and 7L Technic beams featured in triangles above were used in Dark Azure color in the Bugatti. You won't find them in any of retail sets as of the time of this comment. Same goes for half bushings, some other elements including Dark Blue, Trans-Clear and Trans-Red colors (all Bricklink color names).